incremental extract not working with tap-csv
My meltano.yml looks as follows:
version: 1
default_environment: dev
project_id: e8a37ae0-dcd8-4dde-9ebb-abc4c886f101
environments:
- name: dev
- name: staging
- name: prod
plugins:
  extractors:
  - name: tap-csv
    variant: meltanolabs
    pip_url: git+https://github.com/MeltanoLabs/tap-csv.git
    config:
      files:
      - path: _data/
        entity: csv
        keys:
        - id
    metadata:
      '*':
        replication-method: INCREMENTAL
        replication-key: id
  loaders:
  - name: target-jsonl
    variant: andyh1203
    pip_url: target-jsonl


the csv file looks like this (file path = ./_data/a.csv):
id,name,age
1,harry,33
2,rob,45
5,james,22
6,james,2

I am running the following command:
meltano run tap-csv target-jsonl

Expected result
incrementally append any new data in csv files in _data folder to target output location
Actual result
meltano always appends all the data a.k.a full load
Why is incremental load not working?
